# AWS DynamoDB index did not get populated

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a table with some data already. Then I created a few indexes over time. The oldest index has all the items, but two other indexes I created recently were empty. Today I deleted those two indexes and created again. Now they have only 19 items out of 1564 in the table.

I have the same structure but in different region for testing and it all works just fine.

Can somebody explain what's going on, please?

Edit: Here are screenshots of the table and indexes. Number has increased due to new items been added to the table.
[image: The table settings]

[image: Three indexes]

Comment: What do you have the capacity settings for the table and index set to? provisioned or on-demand? if provisioned, what values for RCU/WCU?

Comment: @kirk Hi, I've added screenshots. Basically, all the setting are default. Please have a look.

Comment: Are there any items in the table with values in the "user_id" or "challenge_code" in them. If so, how many of each? DynamoDB can create sparse indexes.

Comment: @Kirk Every item in the table has(must have) all the fields filled with a value. I'm checking that before sending data to DynamoDB. There are no empty filed in the table, I checked manually. Those fields are not unique. ID is the only unique field, of course.